# Deslineamiento de elementos en barra menú superior Bootstrap HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dispongo de un menú en el cual tengo varias etiquetas, dos de ellas **desplegables** (infantil, se despliega correctamente) y un icono de "**bars**" que a su vez debe contener dos elementos en el desplegable (colegios y empresas). Es en éste último donde hay un error. **Si paso el ratón por encima del botón/icono "bars" se me descuadran los elementos que le siguen (acceso clientes, facebook, home, whatsapp).**

**¿A qué se debe?**
Os dejo el código HTML (reducido a esa parte) y CSS para que os lo podáis entender.

```css
/*
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
*/
/* 
    Created on : 08-oct-2015, 11:29:25
    Author     : WEBMASTER, INGESIST
*/
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pathway+Gothic+One');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

.header{
    background:transparent;
}

.con-borde{
    border-bottom: #555 solid medium;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.h1,
.h2,
.h3,
.h4,
.h5,
.h6 {
    font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 400; 
}

figcaption>h2 {

    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* +++++++++++ NAVBAR SUPERIOR +++++++++++ */

.navbar-sup {
    background: #0095a6;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 3000;
    font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

@media (min-width:1000px)and (max-width:1200px){
    .navbar-sup {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}

#owl{
    top: 50px;
}
/* --------- brand ------------ */
.navbar-sup .navbar-brand{
    color: #F3F2F0;
    background: #333;  
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}
.navbar-sup .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-sup .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #5e5e5e;
}
.navbar-sup .navbar-brand .fa{
    line-height: 0.7;
}
/* ---------- menu ---------- */

.navbar-sup .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff ;
}
.navbar-sup .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-sup .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color:#333333;
    background-color: transparent;
}
@media(max-width:1000px){
    .navbar-sup .navbar-nav {
        color: #fff ;
        background: rgba(0,149,166,0.8);
    }
    .navbar-sup .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-sup .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
        color:#333333;
        background: #0095a6;
    }
    .navbar-sup .navbar-nav{
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
    }
}
/* ------- toggle --------- */
.navbar-sup .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #ddd;
}
.navbar-sup .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-sup .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.navbar-sup .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-sup .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-sup .navbar-form {
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
.navbar-sup .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-sup .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-sup .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

/*  +++++++++++ OTROS ELEMENTOS DE MENÚ DE NAVEGACIÓN ++++++++++++++++ */
.navbar-sup .navbar-right{
    display: block !important;
}
.navbar-sup .navbar-nav > li > a.acceso{
    background: #333333;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.navbar-sup .navbar-nav > li > a.acceso:hover,
.navbar-sup .navbar-nav > li > a.acceso:focus {
    color: #5e5e5e;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Efecto rotación */
@media(min-width:1000px ){
    .navbar-sup .navbar-nav > li > a.giro,
    .navbar-sup .navbar-nav > li > a.giro:visited{
        color: #fff;
        margin: auto 0px auto 5px ;
    }
    .navbar-sup .navbar-nav > li > a.giro:hover{
        color:#5e5e5e;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
        -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
        -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
        -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;

        transform: rotate(-360deg);
        transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
}
.activo{
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
/*  +++++++++++ FOOTER ++++++++++++++++ */

.footer{
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background: #F2F2F2 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border-top:1px solid #E3E3E3;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    margin: 30px 0px 0px;
}
.footer p{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #797979;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 19px;
}
/* +++++++++++++ MAPA ++++++++++++++++ */

#map {
    height:220px;
    width: available;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.gm-style-iw * {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.gm-style-iw h4, .gm-style-iw p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.gm-style-iw a {
    color: #4272db;
}
/*  +++++++++++ OTROS ++++++++++++++++ */
.imp-link{
    color:#5b3a73;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
.imp-link a{
    color:#0095a6;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 110%;
}
.imp-link a:hover{
    font-size:100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}



p span .displaynone { display:none; }

/* Slider */

.fullwidth {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: available;/* initial */
}

.slider { margin: 0; }
.slider .slide { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

.slick-prev {
    left: 0;
    background: red;
}
.slick-next {
    right: 0;
    background: red;
}
.slick-dots {
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0; /* Fixes the visible horizontal scroll bar */
}

/* texto */
.wt {
    color: #fff;
}
.b{
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.l {
    font-size: larger;
}
.arriba{
    margin-top: -10px;
}
.margen-dcho {
    margin-right:10px;
}
.margen-izdo{
    padding-left: 10%;
}

.separador{
    height:50px;
    width: available;
}
.destacado{
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight:bold;
}
/* ++++++++++++++ HR ++++++++++++++++++++ */

hr {border: 0; border-top: 2px solid #ddd; border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd; height:0;margin-bottom: 60px;margin-top: 80px; border-style: solid;}
.decorated, .decorated-1, .decorated-2, .decorated-3, .decorated-5,.texto-extras,.texto-contacto,.texto-tambien,.texto-natacion,.texto-fitness,.texto-cumple,.texto-campus,.texto-galeria,.texto-empresas,.texto-servicios{border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #0095a6; border-bottom: 2px solid #0095a6; height:0; border-style: solid; text-align:center;}
.decorated-4{border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #0095a6; border-bottom: 2px solid #0095a6; height:0; border-style: solid; text-align:left;}
.decorated:after {position: relative; top: -18px; content: url(../img/iconos/pin.jpg);height: 44px;padding: 7px;}
.decorated-1:after {position: relative; top: -18px; content: url(../img/iconos/nadador.png);height: 44px;padding: 7px;}
.decorated-2:after {position: relative; top: -22px; content: url(../img/iconos/fitness.jpg);height: 44px;padding: 7px;}
.decorated-3:after {position: relative; top: -22px; content: url(../img/iconos/fiesta.jpg);height: 44px;padding: 7px;}
.decorated-4:after {position: relative; top: -22px; content: url(../img/iconos/empresa.jpg);height: 44px;padding: 7px;}
.decorated-5:after {position: relative; top: -22px; content: url(../img/iconos/galeria.jpg);height: 44px;padding: 7px;}
hr.texto-extras{margin-top: 0px !important;}
.texto-extras:after {position: relative; top:-17px; content:"SERVICIOS ADICIONALES";font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 800;line-height: 34px; color: #aaa;background: #fff;padding: 10px;}
.texto-contacto:after {position: relative; top:-17px; content:"CONTÁCTANOS CON UN CLICK...";font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 30px; font-weight: 800;line-height: 34px; color: #aaa;background: #fff;padding: 10px;}
.texto-tambien:after {position: relative; top:-17px; content:"... O TAMBIÉN";font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 800;line-height: 34px; color: #aaa;background: #fff;padding: 10px;}
.texto-natacion:after {position: relative; top:-17px; content:"NATACIÓN";font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 30px; font-weight: 800;line-height: 34px; color: #aaa;background: #fff;padding: 10px;}
.texto-fitness:after {position: relative; top:-17px; content:"FITNESS";font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 30px; font-weight: 800;line-height: 34px; color: #aaa;background: #fff;padding: 10px;}
.texto-cumple:after {position: relative; top:-17px; content:"CUMPLEAÑOS";font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 30px; font-weight: 800;line-height: 34px; color: #aaa;background: #fff;padding: 10px;}
.texto-campus:after {position: relative; top:-17px; content:"CAMPUS";font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 30px; font-weight: 800;line-height: 34px; color: #aaa;background: #fff;padding: 10px;}
.texto-empresas:after {position: relative; top:-17px; content:"EMPRESAS";font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 30px; font-weight: 800;line-height: 34px; color: #aaa;background: #fff;padding: 10px;}
.texto-galeria:after {position: relative; top:-17px; content:"GALERÍA";font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 30px; font-weight: 800;line-height: 34px; color: #aaa;background: #fff;padding: 10px;}
.texto-servicios:after{position: relative; top:-17px; content:"OTROS SERVICIOS";font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; font-size: 30px; font-weight: 800;line-height: 34px; color: #aaa;background: #fff;padding: 10px;}
/* ++++++++++++++++ IMAGENES ++++++++++++++ */
.panel img{
    width: 150px;
}
.horario{
    max-width: available;
}
.img-effect {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
}
.img-effect:hover {
    opacity: .7;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95,0.95);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.98,0.98);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
    position: relative;

}

.sombra{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
    filter: shadow(color=#999999, direction=135, strength=2);
}
figure{
    background: #F3F4F3;
}
figure img{
    padding: 3px;
}

figcaption p{
    color: #777;
    font-weight:500;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    padding-right: 10px;

}
figcaption hr{border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd; height:0; border-style: solid;}
.servicios {
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 100px;
    width: 130px;
}
.servicios img{
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}
#inicio{
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
}
.max-ancho{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

/*   ++++++++++++++ FORMULARIO +++++++++++++++  */
#contact{
    padding:0;
}

.contact-text{
    margin:45px auto;
}

.mail-message-area{
    width:100%;
    padding:0 15px;
}

.mail-message{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255, 0.8) !important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
    transition: all 0.7s;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.not-visible-message{
    height:0px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.visible-message{
    height:auto;
    opacity: 1;
    margin:25px auto 0;
}

/* Input Styles */

.form{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    border:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    margin-bottom:25px;
    color:#727272 !important;
    font-size:13px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.form:hover{
    border:1px solid #8BC3A3;
}

.form:focus{
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    border:1px solid #8BC3A3;
}

.textarea{
    height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* Generic Button Styles */

.button{
    padding:8px 12px;
    background:#0A5175;
    display: block;
    width:120px;
    margin:10px 0 0px 0;
    border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:0.8em;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.10);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.10);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.10);
}

.button:hover{
    background:#343e93;
    color:white;
}

/* Send Button Styles */

.form-btn{
    width:180px;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    padding:15px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#8BC3A3;
    border:none;
    border-radius:3px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    margin:auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.10);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.10);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.10);
}

.form-btn:hover{
    background:#5986a9;
    color: white;
    border:none;
}

.form-btn:active{
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.enlace{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.semibold{
    font-weight: 600;
}
.modal{
    z-index: 4000;
}

.otros{
 padding: 18px;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta property="og:image" content="img/logos/logo-min.png">
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" >
        <meta name="googlebot" content="NOODP, follow">
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="img/favicon.ico/apple-icon-57x57.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="img/favicon.ico/apple-icon-60x60.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/favicon.ico/apple-icon-72x72.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="img/favicon.ico/apple-icon-76x76.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/favicon.ico/apple-icon-114x114.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="img/favicon.ico/apple-icon-120x120.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/favicon.ico/apple-icon-144x144.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="img/favicon.ico/apple-icon-152x152.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="img/favicon.ico/apple-icon-180x180.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="img/favicon.ico/android-icon-192x192.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="img/favicon.ico/favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="img/favicon.ico/favicon-96x96.png">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="img/favicon.ico/favicon-16x16.png">

        <!--css -->
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap-mod.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Slider -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layerslider/css/layerslider.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layerslider/css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="layerslider/js/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Owl Carousel Assets -->
        <link href="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--mis estilos -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#desplegable1").css('display','none');
    $("#desplegable2").css('display','none');

    $(".infantil").mouseover(function() {
     $("#desplegable1").show('slow');
    });

    $(".infantil").mouseleave(function() {
     $("#desplegable1").hide('slow');
    });
    
    $(".infantil").hover(
     function(){
      $("#desplegable1").css({"background-color":"#0095a6"});
     } 
    );
    
    $(".otros").mouseover(function() {
     $("#desplegable2").show('slow');
    });

    $(".otros").mouseleave(function() {
     $("#desplegable2").hide('slow');
    });
    
    $(".otros").hover(
     function(){
      $("#desplegable2").css({"background-color":"#0095a6"});
     } 
    );
   });
  </script>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            .ls-layer,
            .ls-layer * {
                font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', sans-serif;
                font-weight: normal;
                text-shadow: none !important;
                font-size: 30px;
                color:#333;
                top:50px;
            }

            .ls-s-1 {
                border-radius: 100px;
                -moz-border-radius: 100px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
                font-weight: normal;
            }
            .bg-translucido{
                background: #fff;
                opacity: .50; /* Standard: FF gt 1.5, Opera, Safari, CSS3 */
                filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* IE lt 8 */
                -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=50)"; /* IE 8 */
                -khtml-opacity: .50; /* Safari 1.x */
                -moz-opacity: .50; /* FF lt 1.5, Netscape */
            }

            .plus,
            .plus2 {
                text-align: center;
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px; 
                font-size: 50px;
                line-height: 50px;
                background: #eee;
            }

            .plus {
                color: #3b173d;
            }

            .plus2 {
                color: #1e73be;
            }

            .text,
            .text2 {
                margin: 0px;
                display: inline-block !important;
                padding: 5px 20px 5px 10px;
            }

            .text {
                color: #333;
                background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
                border-radius: 0px !important;
            }

            .text2 {
                color: #1e73be;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Barra superior todo lo ancho de la página. Fuera del container principal-->
        <div class="header">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-sup navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navegacion">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                            <i class="fa fa-bookmark-o fa-2x"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse text-center">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                            <li><a href="natacion.html">NATACIÓN</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Easo/index.html">ESCUELA</a></li>
       <li><a href="fitness.html">FITNESS</a></li>
       
       <!-- Desplegable infantil -->
                            <li class="infantil"><a href="infantil.html">INFANTIL</a>
        <ul id="desplegable1">
         <li><a href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF;">&nbsp;&nbsp;EXTRAESCOLARES&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF;">VACACIONES</a></li>
        </ul>  
       </li>
       
                            <li><a href="cumpleaños.html">CUMPLEAÑOS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="bienestar.html">BIENESTAR</a></li>
                            <li><a href="galeria.html">GALERÍA</a></li>
       
       <!--Desplegable para: colegios y empresas.-->
       <!--<li><a href="colegios.html">COLEGIOS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="empresas.html">EMPRESAS</a></li>-->
       <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg otros" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
        <li class="otros">
         <ul id="desplegable2">
          <li><a href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF;">COLEGIOS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF;">EMPRESAS</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       </i>

                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a class="acceso" href="area-clientes.html" title="area clientes">ACCESO A CLIENTES</a></li>
                            <li><a class="giro" href="https://www.facebook.com/escolapioscentrodeportivo/?fref=ts" ><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-lg"></i></a></li>
       <li><a class="giro" href="contacto.html"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a role="button" class="giro hidden-xs" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="601004597" data-original-title="WHATSAPP:" title="WHATSAPP:"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-lg"></i></a>             
                                <a class="giro visible-xs" href="whatsapp://send?text=URL" title="whatsapp"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-lg"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

        <!-- Zona script-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script/bootstrap/npm.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor organiza tu código, al ejecutarlo se ve que tiene errores en los estilos ya que el menú no queda de forma horizontal, adicional a eso no es necesario que subas toda la estructura ni todos los estilos de tu sitio únicamente con subir lo que realmente pertenece a esa sesión es suficiente

Comment: Los estilos añadidos son los necesarios. He ejecutado y me carga/funciona correctamente aunque no realice lo que explico en la duda.